# Unresolved reference in mutableListOf jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following code:

```
val musu = MusuButton(buttonText = "hmmm" , checkCorrect = {})
val  gridItems = mutableListOf<MusuButton>()
```

The `musu` val can see the `MusuButton` just fine. I am getting an unresovled reference in the `mutableListOf<MusuButton>`

It says the MusuButton is unresolved reference,

Comment: Most probably `MusuButton` is Compose **function**, and `mutableListOf` expects a **class** parameter. What's the expected result?

Comment: You are correct MusuButton is a compose function.

Comment: @Phillip Dukhov I am trying to build a grid to replace the experimenatl LazyVerticalGird

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Compose's experimental views. Experimental doesn't mean there are any bugs in them, it just means that the API may be changed in the future, and I doubt anyone will develop alternative libraries. You can copy the source code of `LazyVerticalGird` to yourself and modify it as you see fit, if you want to avoid future updates to the API